# IP Spoofing using Apache Traffic Server

Tags: spoofing, apache-traffic-server

Can we achieve IP-Spoofing via Apache Traffic Server ? 
Name of parameter in records.config and any other conf file will be really helpful.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by IP-Spoofing? ATS can act as a forward transparent proxy (https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/en/latest/admin-guide/configuration/transparent-proxy.en.html), but that may not be what you are looking for.

Comment: @MilesLibbey Suppose if i am using ATS as my proxy. Generally when it communicates with server, it uses it's own ip address. I want it to use client's ip address.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is a TCP based protocol, so, the server has to know and use the IP of the actual client (ATS or a user-agent) talking to it -- true IP spoofing isn't feasible for ATS or any other proxy. However, by [default](https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/en/latest/admin-guide/files/records.config.en.html?#proxy-config-http-insert-squid-x-forwarded-for), ATS will place your client's IP in the conventional X-Forwarded-For: header, and some servers will use that header's value.

Comment: I found how we can enable (IP spoofing) on ATS. It's named as "outbound transparent" mode in ATS.

Comment: I found how we can enable (IP spoofing) on ATS. It's named as "outbound transparent" mode in ATS.  by setting keyword "tr-out:<port-number>" for CONFIG "proxy.config.http.server_ports" we can send client IP to server instead of ATS/proxy IP. But after changing these variables I am not able to achieve "outbound transparent". I mean to say still ATS is sending it's ip address to origin server instead of client IP... :-(